# Changing Locale

Tags: linux-mint, locale

I am using Linux Mint 15

Currently I have my locale as (by using command `locale`):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ar_SA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I want to change `ar_SA.UTF-8` to `en_IN.UTF-8`. How do i achieve this?
Which file shold I be editing?
Cant seem to find any locale file other than `/etc/locale.alias`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Your Locale

You have a mix of several locales, at least en_US and ar_SA. These actually come from environment variables (the names of which `locale` is displaying for you).

If these are only for your user, they may be coming from a setting in your desktop environment. Go into settings and look for language and/or locale settings. There may also be a language selector on the login screen.

## System Default Locale

On Debian-like systems, the system default locale is stored in `/etc/default/locale`. Not all locales are necessarily available (generated), however; if the `locales-all` package isn't installed, the generation is controlled by `/etc/locale.gen`. You can edit both by hand (they're simple text files).

If you decide to edit the files by hand, you'll need to run `locale-gen` to generate any new locales you enabled.

The alternative is to run:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

That should prompt you which locales to generate and which you want as the system default.

Note that it'll give you a simple locale as default (everything will be en_IN.UTF-8). That may be fine; I suspect you can read en_IN messages almost as well as en_US ones. (With only slight annoyances about colo*u*r, etc.). If you want to generate a more complicated set up, you can edit `/etc/default/locale` by hand or by using `update-locale`.

You'll need to log out and back in for the new locale settings to take effect.

Comment: edited `/etc/default/locale` and yup its working

Answer (score -1):

You change all the `LC_...` settings by setting `LC_ALL`

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ export LC_ALL=uk_UA
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="uk_UA"
LC_CTYPE="uk_UA"
LC_MESSAGES="uk_UA"
LC_MONETARY="uk_UA"
LC_NUMERIC="uk_UA"
LC_TIME="uk_UA"
LC_ALL="uk_UA"
```

`locale -a` will show all the locales installed on your system

Comment: For the record, this is a terrible idea. `LC_ALL` should _not_ be `export`ed, it should only be used for temporary overrides.